# How to copy paste e-mail or passwords on a website, which prevents this?

Tags: email, browser, passwords, website, copy-paste

Some (in my opinion badly designed) websites, prevent you copy paste your password or e-mail into "repeat" fields. In my opinion this is an idiotic design making user experience horrible. Especially, if you are a more experienced user. I faced a such a challenge very recently. I was wondering, how to overcome this issue?

I tried to copy paste in to the `value` attribute of the `input` element. This did not work on this particular website.

I tried to disable javascript by pausing in the debugger. This disabled the whole page preventing me to interact with it.

Answer (score -1):

The solution I came up with was to (tested on Firefox)

1. right click field and inspect the element,
2. click on the event and disable the paste routine,
   [image: disabling the javascript routine]
3. paste the e-mail or password into the field itself (not in the inspector),
4. (optional) contact the website provider, informing about the
   terrible decision they made.